# How to use Jexl to validate inputs in JavaScript/React?

Tags: javascript, jexl

I'm working on a project where I need to validate inputs using Jexl in a JavaScript/React application. I'm new to Jexl and I'm having trouble understanding how to use it for validation.

Specifically, I need to validate inputs against a set of rules defined in a Jexl expression. The inputs are dynamic and can change based on user interaction.

To give an example I have a form like this

[image: form1]

The `visible if` column is where I write the jexl syntax by opening a dialog as

[image: dialogSave]

What I'm writing here is that I have a mandatory string `answer` which should be always there.
Then is followed by the questionKey which is the key you see under the `key` column.
The `== "yes"` correspond on the items.

I know this way is valid as per jexl playground testing with a context as

```json
{
  "answer": {
  "yes": "yes"
  }
}
```

What I need is to validate the input visibleIf by checking with jexl and show an error or a red borders when the syntax is invalid based on the context.

I'm not sure that is possible as I was unable to find any example of this.

Comment: have you tried `try catch` ?

Answer (score 1):

After searching I discovered that Jexl does not have a built-in function for validating expressions. However, you can use `try-catch` block to validate user input and provide appropriate responses to users.

Also, in the [Jexl npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jexl) example, they handle invalid expressions using a try-catch block.

[image: Jxel]

here is how you might implement this in JavaScript code.

```js
const isValidJexlExpression = (jexlExpression, context) => {
  try {
    const _ = jexl.evalSync(jexlExpression, context);
    return true;
  } catch (_) {
    return false; 
  }
};

// usage

if(isValidJexlExpression (/* */)) { /* TODO: show error message */ }
```

Comment: yes I would try like this my doubts were also about the context part but I need to figure out that

Comment: @Jakub good luck! if you need any help let me know.